# Unable to use io.read() to grab the user's input after already using it to grab a file's contents

Tags: lua

I've got this program that starts off with the program grabbing a file's contents.

```
local oldprint = print
local print = io.write
-- this was done mainly because the newline from print() wasn't needed

io.input("script.txt")

local script = io.read("*all")

io.close()
```

Then there is a function containing another io.read(), which should allow for the user's input.

```
local functions = {
    [","] = function()
        local input
        repeat
            print("\nAwaiting input... (must be a number)\n")
            input = io.read("*n")
        until input ~= nil
        array[pointer] = input
        print(stringy)
    end
}

functions[","]()
```

I expect it for it to print once, and then grab the input, but it ends up constantly printing.

I've tried using io.flush(), but it didn't work, and I'm not exactly sure what else to try...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By calling `io.input("script.txt")` you set that file as the default input file. Any following calls to io.read() will hence read from that file.

Either use `file:read` instead of `io.read` or reset the input to the standard input stream by calling `io.input(io.stdin)`.

I suggest you refer to the Lua reference manual.

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.8

Answer (score -1):

To use `io.read()`, you have to close the file you opened, because if you have a file open, lua will assume you are reading from the file that you opened.
Try grabbing the input before you open the file